# New to flutter. How to apply word limit on container in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, text, widget, calculator

I tired to make a calculator as first project and used a container with text widget as the dispaly for numbers user enter and i want to set limit on characters so it would stop after there are 15 characters.

here is the code:

````
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(//container I want to impose limit on
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 20, 5, 0),
            child: Text(
              msg,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.blue),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 30, 10, 0),
            child: Text(
              equation,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: equationFontSize),
              maxLines: 1,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 40, 10, 0),
            child: Text(
              result,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: resultFontSize),
            ),
          ), ```
````

Comment: Where do you take user input? You can set limit on user input using the `maxLength` property in a `TextFormField`.

Comment: actually, my user input is from buttons to the container on top (the very first container), ontap any button, the button text is used as input and operations are performed on that, but i guess i should change it to TextFormField.

Comment: If you want to use only `Text` widget, then you can check the `msg` variable's length & if it is greater than 15 characters, trim it or do something else.